# a word should not start with a digit in Java

Tags: java, regex

The string should meet the requirements:

> > > 1.it consist of some words separated by spaces.
> > >
> > > 2.only allow letters,digits,underscores, ' and " in each word
> > >
> > > 3.each word must start with a letter or a quote

Now I wrote this and it doesn't meet the last requirment:

```
public boolean test(String string) {
return string.matches("[A-Za-z0-9_' \"]+");
}
```

If I give an illegal string "this world start with 123digit" , it would return false, but it return true:

```
public boolean test("there is a word start with 123digit"){
\\my previous code return true.
\\so someone PLEASE HELP to implement the method so 
\\ it will return false in such situation.
}
```

also this this situation , it should return false:

```
public boolean test("there is a word start with _underscore"){
\\my previous code return true.
\\so someone PLEASE HELP to implement the method so 
\\ it will return false in such situation.
}
```

Comment: What do you think your regex is doing? Explain it in words. It might help explain to you why it doesn't satisfy requirement 3.

Comment: Note: there are far more characters that Java allows than A-Z a-z and 0-9  I suggest you use the built in tools for checking a string is a valid Java identifier. Character.isJavaIndentiferStart() return true for 48529 characters and Character.isJavaIdentifierPart() return true for 50139 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.matches("^([A-Za-z'\"][A-Za-z0-9_'\"]* *)+$")
```

[Visualization](http://tinyurl.com/ksjrjuh)

Comment: An explanation would go nicely with the code.